# Configure PrimeUI with web application

Tags: html, primefaces, prime-ui

I'm new to prime-ui (PrimeUI is a spin-off project from the popular JSF Component Suite, PrimeFaces). I have downloaded prime-ui-0.8.bundle.zip file from http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html . I want to configure it with my simple web application having html pages. I don't know which css and js files do I need to include so that it will start working.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to files two be located in your page. prime-ui-0.8.min.css and prime-ui-0.8.min.js. These two files are in production folder of the zip file you downloaded. You also need jquery.js and jquery-ui.js in addition to the themeroller theme.